# Accessing Angular's CSS bundle from static HTML

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-cli

When building with the angular-cli the bundles within index.html are versioned and added dynamically. There are a couple .html files I include in the distributed package that are meant to be health checks and interstitial pages for forwarding a user to when their session dies and for a few other boring reasons.

None of these pages really have any javascript or brains to them at all.

I'd like to have access to the same styles.{generatedCacheBuster}.bundle.css file though.

Any clever ideas on how to get the same link to be generated and embedded in these other index files so I don't have to go copying all the perfectly good styles we have available to the angular app?

Comment: You'd like to remove the hash? You could modify the build to get file names and export them in a map file like environment.ts

Comment: No...not really remove the hash. It's valuable. I do need these static html files that are not managed by the angular build to also have the appropriate link to the appropriate asset.